# jquery empty() not working in an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel

I have a modal box in which I have placed some elements in

```
 <a class="incidents" tabindex="0"  id= 'incident0' data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="bottom" data-content=""></a>
 <a class="incidents" tabindex="1"  id= 'incident1' data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="bottom" data-content=""></a>
 <a class="incidents" tabindex="0"  id= 'incident2' data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="bottom" data-content=""></a>
 <a class="incidents" tabindex="0"  id= 'incident3' data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="bottom" data-content=""></a>
```

On the completion of my ajax call, I then populate the elements using a for-loop dynamically, the maximum number of objects I'll get is 4, so I structured it in a way that if there is just 2 objects, it stops at incident2 and breaks out.

```
if (data.incidents.issuesQty != 0) 
   { 
     //console.log('I am here');           
     for (var i = data.incidents.issuesQty - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
     {                  
          if (data.incidents.issues[i].type == "ban")
          {
            $( "#incident"+i ).html("<i class=\"fas fa-ban\"></i>");
            $("#bannedUser" ).html("BANNED");
          }
          if (data.incidents.issues[i].type > 3)
          {
            $( "#incident"+i ).html("<i class=\"fas fa-thermometer-full\"></i>");
          }
          else if(data.incidents.issues[i].type > 2)
          {
            $( "#incident"+i ).html("<i class=\"fas fa-thermometer-half\"></i>");
          }
          else if(data.incidents.issues[i].type < 3)
          {
            $( "#incident"+i ).html("<i class=\"fas fa-thermometer-empty\"></i>");
          }
         $( "#incident"+i ).attr("data-content", '<b>Notes: </b>'+data.incidents.issues[i].notes');
     }
   }
```

The problem is if I have a user which populates the element incident 1 and incident 2, and then I click on another user  that has no incidents i.e the if statement block get's skipped; the element "incident1" still remembers the data from the previous user and still displays it.

I have tried to use use the jQuery empty method right at the start of the ajax success to clear the elements but for some reason it still regurgitates the old data. I also placed a console.log debug to verify that the if-statement gets skipped but still I have an

```
$( "#incident1").empty();
$( "#incident2").empty();
$( "#incident3").empty();
$( "#incident4").empty();
```

Comment: Without seeing a mocked example of the problem it's hard to follow the flow of the logic in order to help you. However I can see there's a syntax error; you're missing a `+` in the final string concatenation. Check the syntax highlighting in the question to spot it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course I made the all time rookie mistake of counting from '1' instead of from '0'. My elements are indexed from 0 to 3, but I am trying to empty from 1 to 4 which meant element 0 was always untouched!